# Getting Null pointer in repo.getBucket() method while writing junit

Tags: java, junit, couchbase

I wrote code for changing the TTL of couchbase docs when some condition becomes true. The code works fine but while writing the junits my code throws a Null Pointer on the `getbucket()` method because the repository is a mock.

Actual code :

```
if(isDiscarded){
    this.repository.getBucket().touch(notification.getNotificationId(),getTTL());
}
```

Junit :

```
doNothing().when(this.repo.getBucket().touch(....));
```

Comment: Nevermind I figured the solution.

Comment: Solution : create a mock bucket in your junit class and return it when getBucket() is used

Comment: Can you try if this works? Add `@Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)` over the `repo` mock declaration, without mocking the bucket.